# Associate a subscription to personal entity in Stripe portal

Tags: stripe-payments

I want to use Stripe portal to manage subscriptions. In my app, an ENTITY is linked to a SUBSCRIPTION.

So a USER can have several ENTITY and subscribe one SUBSCRIPTION for each ENITTY.

My problem is that when a user manage several SUBSCRIPTION in the stripe portal. There is no distinction between Stripe subscriptions. So I want to distinguish them by :

- adding a custom name for each property (for example the ENTITY NAME) but can't find any way to do this
- adding a metadata to the subscription but I can't find any way to display meta data in Stripe

Is there any solution to distinguish several subscriptions ?